# Acronym in the paper title does not appear in uppercase in reference list

Tags: citing, bibtex

I created bibliography using BibTeX. I am using IEEETran style. The paper title in the references list does not show acronyms in upper case. e.g UDP and TCP is shown as udp and tcp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Throw the things you want to maintain your capitalization on into curly braces, e.g. `{TCP}`.

Comment: You can also do this to single letters for things like `The {J}ones approach to fooing a bar`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the reason for this is that Bibtex automatically standardizes the capitalization for consistency, but it's not intelligent enough to distinguish between acronyms and mistakes.  The braces make the capitalization algorithm disregard these words.